# Function setInterval is not working in reactJs

Tags: reactjs, components, setinterval

I want to call some function and update state after a time interval in react component but it is not working as expected. Here is my code.

```
componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log("update")
        setInterval(this.tickingTimer(), 2000)
    }
    tickingTimer(){
        this.state.counter = this.state.counter+1
        console.log("timer");
    }
```

I tried to set interval function in componentDidMount also but it only call once. It is not updating data after interval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must not mutate state, instead use [`setState`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) to update state. Also an interval must not be used within `componentDidUpdate` directly. The best place to have an interval is `componentDidMount` and the callback function to setInterval must not be triggered but passed as reference.

```
componentDidMount(){
    console.log("update")
    this.timerId = setInterval(this.tickingTimer, 2000)
}
tickingTimer(){
    this.setState(prev => ({counter: prevState.counter+1}));
    console.log("timer");
}
componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerId)
}
```

NOTE: clear setInterval in `componentWillUnmount`